# Genexus 15, save PDFs, GIFs, JPGs, WORD documents

Tags: pdf, genexus

I need to save PDFs, GIFs, TIFs, JPGs, etc...how can I do this in Genexus 15 compiling in C#.
After this I have to show the saved documents in a form.
Thank you..

PD: I'm new using Genexus...

Answer (score 0):

This question seems too broad to answer... Will those files be stored in the database or the file system? Or perhaps in an external storage like Amazon's S3?

Will the application store different file types in the same database column, or will there be a filed storing images, another one por PDFs, etc.?

Anyway, here are some documents that may be of some help:

- [Blob data type](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?6704,Blob%20data%20type,) for storing any file in the database (or see [BlobFile data type](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?35536,Blobfile%20data%20type%20-%20Draft,) if using GeneXus Tero, in pre-beta at this moment...)
- [File data type](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?6915,File%20data%20type,) for storing files in the file system
- [Image data type](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?15204,Image%20data%20type,) for storing image files in the database (there is also Audio and Video which work exactly the same way)
- [External Storage for Multimedia](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?31120,External%20Storage%20for%20Multimedia,) explains hot to store multimedia files in an external service.

Hope this helps...